# Bring an element above an absolutely positioned overlay

Tags: css

How can the `h2` element in this [sandbox](https://plnkr.co/edit/md2lIJCbhnEcc1XAbrne?p=preview) be brought up above the overlay?

```
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<h2>Above the overlay</h2>
<div class="overlay"></div>

.overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.8);
  z-index:100;
}

h2 {
   z-index:200;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/md2lIJCbhnEcc1XAbrne?p=preview

Comment: Always include the relevant code in your question, and not just the link to sandbox.

Comment: You don;t need to set the absolute element with a z-index. Only the elements you want to show over it. So a z-index on the '.overlay' of 1 would suffice. More code would be nice as Ori advised so we can help you  set the appropriate visible priority

Comment: ...meant you don-t need z-index on the overlay since its position is absolute. Only the elements you want over the '.overlay'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the position of the element from `static` to `relative` / `absolute` / `fixed`. `position: static` (the default) doesn't allow `z-index` ([demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/hkEuvHOrctVusCF22fUH?p=preview)):

```
h2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index:200;
}
```

Comment: I accepted your answer since it does work for the question/sandbox provided. Unfortunately for me, my sandbox must be missing something important because I had tried that already and it does not work in my actual case. I'll create a new question once I figure out what's different.

Comment: Add a link to the new question here, when you do that. That's interesting :)

Comment: I actually fixed the problem. It was due to a css selector applying a z-index to a far parent of the node I wanted to bring to the foreground. Css doesn't allow a child of a node with lower z-index than its sibbling to be "over" that sibbling. I had to rearrange my HTML hierarchy such that the > * { z-index: X; } selector wouldn't affect my result.

Comment: The old stacking [context problem](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/what-you-may-not-know-about-the-z-index-property--webdesign-16892). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the `h2` should be *in front of* the overlay DIV, change its CSS to:

```
h2 {
    z-index: 200;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
}
```

(I added the white color to make it clearer that it's not behind `overlay`)